# Is there any way of finding users by country?

Tags: support, rankings

The title is exactly my question. Can I find my country fellas? Is there a country ranking?

Comment: **[Top Users from All World Countries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1250968/top-reputation-users-from-all-countries-of-the-world)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. [Data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is for you.

Have a look at this query: [Top users: Any country having atleast 100 reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103129/top-users-any-country-having-atleast-100-reputation?CountryName=india). Here you can pass `CountryName` parameter to search top users for your country.

But it will show users who has edited location detail in his profile.

Comment: +1 do you know the syntax to work out users without a location specified? I tried putting [empty for the countryName](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103129/top-users-any-country-having-atleast-100-reputation?CountryName=) but it didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Yes. [WHERE Location = ''](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103129/top-users-any-country-having-atleast-100-reputation)