# With the UK now having two seemingly active versions of GDPR, at which age should a moderator consider a user underaged?

Tags: support, moderation, legal, age, gdpr

The [FAQ on underage users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102250/369802) states:

> Stack Exchange has decided to limit registration for all people in any EU member nation to users 16 or older, in order to ensure it remains compliant with the laws in all EU member nations, and keeping track of each nation's age threshold in the Terms of Service would be prohibitively expensive, as they may change in the future.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319809/369802) explains a bit more too.

Even under the EU version of GDPR, it seems the [UK already set the age limit lower than 16 years](https://www.betterinternetforkids.eu/en_US/web/portal/practice/awareness/detail?articleId=3017751). They have now also implemented their own version of GDPR, with the same age of consent (13).

But with Brexit happening on January 31st and a transition period (for now) until December 31st, I'm wondering what this means for the moderation of underage users. I found [this source](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/uk-gdpr/) explaining that the UK has made their own version of GDPR, and that it applies now. But the implementation of the EU version of GDPR will only cease to apply at the end of the transition period, so it's also applicable now.

So, does that mean that until December 31st, users from UK still need to be 16? Or, because both the old and new version of GDPR law in the UK state a user has to be 13, can I assume someone aged 13-16 from the UK should no longer be considered as underaged right now?

Comment: I assume nothing has to change here: as long as they're in the EU, the limit of 16 goes, which is the same as that for other EU countries that actually have a limit of 13 years, if they're out of the EU the limit of 13 goes as is the same for all non-EU countries.

Comment: @ErikA The UK left the EU on 31 January 2020.  The new UK-GDPR also came into effect on 31 January 2020.  However, the EU GDPR continues to apply in the UK during the "Transition period", which is currently scheduled to end on on 31 December 2020.  The question is thus, how do SE choose to handle the situation during the Transition period.

Comment: Then the age limit is 13 as per the ToS and the guidance in the FAQ. Stack Exchange has chosen not to have country-specific age-limits, but only EU/non-EU (possibly violating laws in some countries), seems like there's no need for a specific case for the UK, especially since they also want to have the limit at 13 years

Comment: [Will Stack Exchange EU terms still apply to Britain now that BREXIT has finished?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/48851/29997) - Similar question at Law.SE

Comment: @ErikA Except that the [Withdrawal Agreement](https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainers/brexit-deal-withdrawal-agreement) requires that "... _any EU law applying to the UK under the agreement should have the same effect as it has in EU member states_" for the duration of the Transition period.  Like I said, it is a decision that must be made by SE Inc, but I suspect they will continue to err on the side of legal caution, as most other tech companies appear to be doing.

Comment: I agree with the prior two comments. The moderator at [Law.SE says: yes (16), until year's end](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/48853), the accepted answer is no. It's OK for them to ask there and not here, and we can't cross site dupe; so it has been asked, though the answer is not concrete.

Answer (score 11):

The GDPR requires that the [age of consent is between 13 and 16 years of age](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-8-gdpr/), where it is up to the EU member nations to choose which age to mention in their national laws. The UK has chosen to set the age at 13 years.

SE Inc choose to apply the upper limit of the age in its TOS for citizens of EU member nations to avoid having to check (and monitor) the national laws on age of consent for all twenty-something EU member nations. It would also have been within their rights to choose an even higher age, like 21.

As of Jan 31 2020, the UK is no longer an EU member nation, so any special rules in the SE TOS for citizens EU member nations no longer apply to UK citizens.

Thus, SE Inc would not violate its own TOS, nor any GDPR regulation, if it allows 13 to 15 year old UK citizens to use its services.

Comment: "Violating" your own TOS in favor of a user is mostly a non-issue anyway. Who would have a case to sue over that?